# Class inheriting from Pyomo Block

Tags: pyomo

So, I am developing a Concrete energy model and I want to make use of the Block feature in Pyomo. In particular, I want to create a Class, DieselGenerator, which is a child of Block. I want to have the same features of Block in DieselGenerator such as indexing and so on, but also provide the class with some model-specific functions. Here the code for the class generation. Calling the super function gives the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot apply a Set operator to an indexed Block component
> (DieselGenerator)"

Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
Class DieselGenerator(Block):

def __init__(self,d,t):
       
    super().__init__(self,d,t)

    def construct(self, name, d,file="BlockGen.yaml"):     

        try: 
            f = open(file)
            generators_dict = yaml.load(f)
            return generators_dict[d][name]
        except:
            print("Generator file not found. Verify name and directory path")

    def power_output_rule(self):
        return self.fuel_cost == self.fuel_cost* self.status

    def fuel_consumption_rule(self):
        power_min = self.rated_power* self.status
        return self.output== power_min

    self.d = d
    self.t = t

    self.rated_power = Param(initialize = construct(self, "rated_power",self.d))    

    self.output = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
    self.status = Var(within=Boolean)
    self.fuel_cost = Param(within=NonNegativeReals, initialize= construct(self,"fuel_cost",self.d))

    self.fuel_consumption = Constraint(rule = fuel_consumption_rule)
    self.power_output = Constraint(rule = power_output_rule)`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback in your post.

Comment: it'd be very helpful to see your imports, it's not clear where `Block` comes from.
Pyomo has two main interfaces: `environ` and `kernel`. `environ` components aren't designed to be easily subclassed. If you want to do that, then you should take a look at `kernel`:
https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/index.html